# Unable to open "prepare your app" link on Google OAuth consent screen Verification Status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to make Google OAuth consent screen public, but I got "URL not found" error when I clicked "prepare your app" link in the "Verification Status" section.

What should I do?

[image: Google OAuth content screen setting page]

[image: URL not found error]

- I'm an administrator, so probably not the matter of access permission.
- I sent an inquiry to Google Cloud Support, but they said API is out of their support scope and recommended me to ask this question on stackoverflow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on [this](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) document regarding how to set up OAuth 2.0 in your GCP project?

Comment: @rsalinas Yes. I followed the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is an internal problem with google console. You should wait until google fixes it.
2. You can use your app by going to credentials and creating credentials. 
   Thanks